# Remove all Optional empty/null values from arraylist in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-9

I need to remove all empty/null values from `List<Optional<String>>`.

Example:

```
List<Optional<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(Optional.empty());
list.add(Optional.of("Str1"));
list.add(Optional.of("Str2"));
list.add(Optional.of("Str3"));
list.add(Optional.of("Str4"));
list.add(Optional.of("Str5"));
list.add(Optional.empty());
list.add(Optional.ofNullable(null));
```

---

Currently, I'm using one of the below approaches:

**Way 1:**

```
List<String> collect = list.stream()
                   .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                   .map(obj ->obj.get())
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Way 2:**

```
List<Optional<String>> emptlist = new ArrayList<>();
emptlist.add(Optional.empty());
list.removeAll(emptlist);
```

**Is there any other better way?**

Comment: Do you want to create a filtered copy of the list and transform optionals to Strings, or to remove empty elements from the list? Option 1 does the former, Option 2 does the latter. So they don't do the same thing at all. If the latter, using removeIf() would be much clearer.

Comment: What is the question exactly ? But use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-). Simply like `list.removeIf(o -> !o.isPresent());`

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help (I was able to read that before), you are still not clear, first you ask to "_remove all empty/null values from `List<Optional<String>>.`_" then you said in comments "_-need separate copy of filtered list_". So what is it ? Please provide a [mcve] explaining what you expect.

Comment: see [Filtering a Stream of Optionals in Java](http://www.baeldung.com/java-filter-stream-of-optional). Also, IMO the first approach is as clean as it gets with java-8 though you could do `map(Optional::get)` rather than `map(obj ->obj.get())`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With ***Java9***, you can do this using the newly added **[`Optional::stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--)** API :

```
List<String> collect = list.stream()
               .flatMap(Optional::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> This method can be used to transform a *`Stream` of optional elements* to
>   a *`Stream` of present value elements*.

Sticking with ***Java8***, the ***Way1*** in the question is good enough IMHO -

```
List<String> collect = list.stream()
               .filter(Optional::isPresent)
               .map(Optional::get) // just a small update of using reference
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

`removeIf` is the shortest way to do that :

```
list.removeIf(x -> !x.isPresent());
```

Comment: only if that list supports removal

Comment: @Eugene: that’s implied by the OP’s second variant using `removeAll`. But even that can be simplified to a single liner: `list.removeAll(List.of(Optional.empty()));`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to have a little fun or understand working of Optionals and Streams better (Java 8):

```
List<String> collect=list.stream().
                                   map(z->z.map(Stream::of)).
                                   flatMap(ox->ox.orElseGet(Stream::empty)).
                                   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. The first map function converts Optional[String] to Optional 
   [Stream[String]]. A Stream String[Optional 
   [Stream[String]]] is thus passed forward
2. The "map" part of flatmap converts each Optional[Stream[String]] to Stream[String]. All empty Optionals are replaced by an empty Stream. Now we have Stream[Stream[String]].
3. The "flat" part converts Stream[Stream[String]] to Stream[String].